# findBy() todos os registros com duas condições

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2

Estou tentando trabalhar com `findBy()` em uma aplicação feita em Symfony2. Gostaria de colocar duas condições no FindBy ou misturar com Where se possível, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
$properties = $em->getRepository('PropertyBundle:Property')->findBy(array(),array('name' => 'ASC'));
```

Eu gostaria de incluir a condições `active = '1'` para escolher apenas os registros que contem o status(active) ativo.

```
$properties = $em->getRepository('CitraxPropertyBundle:Property')->findBy(array(),array('name' => 'ASC'),array('active' => 1));
```

Comment: Por que o primeiro array do `findBy` está vazio?

Answer (score 3):

Aqui estão alguns exemplos da própria documentação do doctrine.
[Site do doctrine sessão 7.8.2. By Simple Conditions site](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)

```
    <?php
// $em instanceof EntityManager

// All users that are 20 years old
$users = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->findBy(array('age' => 20));

// All users that are 20 years old and have a surname of 'Miller'
$users = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->findBy(array('age' => 20, 'surname' => 'Miller'));

// A single user by its nickname
$user = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->findOneBy(array('nickname' => 'romanb'));
```

A documentação oficial do symfony também tem alguns exemplos [Documantação symfony que fala sobre findby](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Este exemplo está no link acima

```
    // query for one product matching by name and price
$product = $repository->findOneBy(
    array('name' => 'foo', 'price' => 19.99)
);

// query for all products matching the name, ordered by price
$products = $repository->findBy(
    array('name' => 'foo'),
    array('price' => 'ASC')
);
```